# How to implement search tool get values in dropdown ArcGIS JavaScript 3.x

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

How to get point?

When search button clicked  i am trying search button click to go  to point in ArcGIS JavaScript my code is this.

How to push the values into search button?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getresults(){
  try{
    require([
      "esri/tasks/query", "esri/tasks/QueryTask","esri/geometry/Geometry",
      "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(
      Query, QueryTask, Geometry,
      dom, on
    ){
      var selectdrp=document.getElementById("drplayer");
      var layerId=selectdrp.options[selectdrp.selectedIndex].value;
      var selfield=document.getElementById("layer");
      var seltext=selfield.options[selfield.selectedIndex].text;
      var selectionObject = document.getElementById("selvalue");
      var select = selectionObject.options[selectionObject.selectedIndex].value;

      var dyurl= "http://10.1.0.246/arcgis/rest/services/Warangal/MapServer/" + layerId;
      var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask(dyurl);
      query = new esri.tasks.Query();
      query.returnGeometry = false;
      query.where = "1=1";
      query.outFields = ["*"];
      queryTask.execute(Query, ZoomToGeometry)

   });
  }
  catch(ex) {
    alert(ex.toString());
  }
}


function ZoomToGeometry(results) {
  try {
    var featureSet = results.features[0].Geometry;
    var pointGraphic = document.getElementById("select");

    map.graphics.clear();
    var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();
    // Loop through features in the featureSet and add them to the map.
    for (var i=0, il=featureSet.features.length; i<il; i++) {
    // Get the current feature from the featureSet.
    // Feature is a graphic
    var graphic = featureSet.features[i];
    graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
    graphic.setInfoTemplate(pointGraphic);

    //Add graphic to the map graphics layer.
    map.graphics.add(graphic);
  }


  // var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
  // for (var attr in featureAttributes) {
  //   var graphic=document.createElement("option");
  //   graphic.text=featureAttributes[attr];
  //   graphic.value=featureAttributes[attr];
  //   map.graphic.add(graphic);
  //   Graphic = graphic;
  //   resultItems.push("<b>" + attr + ":</b>  " + featureAttributes[attr] + "<br>");
  // }          
  //}

  }
  catch(ex) {
    alert(ex.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First fix those lines :

```
var queryTask = new QueryTask(dyurl);
var query = new Query();`
```

then, fix the query, to get the values you want `query.where = "FIELDNAME = '"+ select +"'";` where *FIELDNAME* is an attribute field of your feature layer

`query.returnGeometry = true;` *returnGeometry* should be set at **true** as you need it in your *ZoomToGeometry* function

`queryTask.execute(query, ZoomToGeometry);` you must use the lower case *query* as the first parameter of *queryTask()*